# Exclude /assets folder from building/exporting it to APK

Tags: android, adt

I use expansion files in my project, and I have placed all my assets into expansion file. So I access the assets from expansion file. Now that all my assets are in expansion file. I don't want to build them while building android application, but I don't want also to remove them from project path as they are source controlled with SVN. I tried to use eclipse->exclude form build which has no effect. So can any one suggest is there way in Eclipse to exclude asset folder?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you rename `assets` folder? Maybe tomorrow you'll want to use the `assets` folder. You better not touch special android folders and create your own.

Usually I create `_assets` and `_drawable` folders. Such folders (starting with underscore) are not processed by android build.

Comment: @Leonidas I just want to avoid svn changes by renaming that folder, however I vote your answer up, as it is potential work around.

Comment: svn move asserts _asserts. just one line )
Maybe someone knows how to exclude assert and will answer later... but I think you better to rename it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Gradle build you can use [`android.aaptOptions`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-aapt-options) to configure this:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        def defaultIgnorePattern = '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        ignoreAssetsPattern defaultIgnorePattern + ':descript.ion:!*.yuml'
    }
}
```

I use it to not package `descript.ion` files in general and yuml diagrams which I keep in `src/main/assets` next to my DB scripts.